# How to prevent javascript execution when appended to an url?

Tags: javascript, web, xss

something like this

```
https://example.com/my_account/login?"><script>alert(1347)</script>
```

when I enter this url in a browser it shows an alert.
how to prevent that?

Edit: This is a java web application using Struts framework...

Comment: It does that with any URL, or only URLs pointing to your login script?

Comment: What browser are you using? I cannot get this to work on Google Chrome

Comment: I suspect it's a bug in the login script, you'll need to post its code. It's apparently echoing the parameter back to the browser.

Comment: @dylanweber - I am using firefox 12.0

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you have to escape the string in order to prevent XSS. A good guide is at:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

You didn't mention which server and/or client-side frameworks you are using. But essentially, you have to escape the string provided to you by the user to encode the <, > &, and other dangerous characters which could inject code into your html. Most web frameworks have this functionality. In java, with owasp-esapi-java, it is:

```
String safe = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML( request.getParameter( "input" ) );
```

And you can output `safe` inside html. Hope that helps. If you are using a specific framework, (rails, play, django, struts, jsp, something else), please ask another question about XSS prevention with that framework.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what type of content you are receiving from the outside, and handle it appropriately before sending it to any browser.

If you consider it's text, then:

- if it's output as part of text within the HTML, you should appropriately escape at least `<` and `&` by replacing everything that is necessary with the correct HTML entities
- if it's output as part of an attribute within the HTML, the same applies plus at least `"` and `'`.

If you consider it's HTML, that you need to select which elements you accept (for instance `<b>`, `<i>`, etc.), and filter out anything else.

How you do it depends on the language/framework you are using.